# SQL query - return new table after counting number of rows per date

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I've run a query using a join clause that generates a table as follows:

```
Name, Colour, Date
John, Blue, 01/01/2021
Betty, Green, 01/01/2021
Bob, Blue, 01/01/2021 
Mark, Green, 03/02/2021
Jane, Red, 03/02/2021
```

I want to create another query that counts the number of times a colour occurs for a specific date. So the result would return something like the following:

```
Colour, ColourTotal, Date
Blue, 2, 01/01/2021
Green, 1, 01/01/2021
Green, 1, 03/02/2021
Red, 1, 03/02/2021
```

I can't figure it out. When I try to nest SELECT queries I keep getting an error about aggregation. I have no background in SQL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Can you share your initial query? that would be helpful to give you a more accurate suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should aggregate only at the outer query, like this:

```
SELECT Colour, Date, COUNT(*) AS ColourTotal
FROM 
   ( 
      SELECT ... 
   ) AS ColoursPerDate
GROUP BY Colour, Date
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT color,
   date,
   Count(*) AS colorTotal
FROM   table
GROUP  BY color,
      date
```